# Clear a field when state changes - Salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, salesforce-flow

I want to make it so that when you **fill** in a field (in case) X and **go** to a state, it is **deleted** (this field should be saved in the history, I think this is done by default). This is necessary so that the user does not have to be hitting the pencil and erasing the message that comes from another state.

As I saw with a Trigger it can be done, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need code for it, you could do it with config changes (workflow / flow / process builder). But if you're really after a trigger - something like that.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case(before update){
    for(Case c : trigger.new){
        Case old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
        if(c.Status != old.Status){
            c.Description = null; // whichever field you want to wipe
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit** about 0 code solutions

Look into workflows, flows and process builder. Actually if you're starting fresh maybe focus on flows, the other 2 are bit passe and SF recommends migrating away: https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/go-with-the-flow-whats-happening-with-workflow-rules-and-process-builder

Have a look at these and if you're stuck: consider posting at dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is really for code related stuff, you'll reach more admins over there.

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-builder
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform-app-builder-certification-maintenance-winter-21/get-handson-with-flow-before-save-trigger-when-certain-record-changes-are-made
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301451/trigger-flow-if-a-specific-field-on-the-updated-record-changed
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_prior_values_flow.htm&type=5&release=230

Comment: Thanks!!
I have 2 validation rules that control that the field is not empty when passing from one state to another. Can it be done without Trigger?

Comment: in workflow-ish syntax what you need could look more or less `IF(ISCHANGED(Status) && !(validation_rule_1_condition_here || validation_rule_2_condition_here)) THEN wipe the field`. Exact syntax for flows, optimisations if the val rules contain lots of similar parts - you'll have to do it yourself.